# How to obtain number of commits behind/ahead with libgit2sharp?

Tags: git, libgit2, libgit2sharp, git-rev-list

It's possible to obtain the number of commits behind/ahead using `git rev-list` command. I am trying to achieve the same thing using `libgit2sharp` library but the library is not fully documented so I couldn't find how to.

I'm looking for an example for obtaining behind/ahead commit numbers with [`libgit2sharp`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp).

Comment: If you just want to get the commits behind/ahead between a local branch and its tracked branch, you could just use the `Branch.TrackingDetails` property, which behind the scene uses the `HistoryDivergence` class that Jason Haslam is refering to in his answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Completing the answer given by Jason Haslam... This is an example of how to use `HistoryDivergence` to get the number of commits ahead and behind of each branch:

```
using (var repo = new Repository("/path/to/repo"))
{
     foreach (Branch b in repo.Branches)
     {
               // if branch does not have a remote b.TrackingDetails.AheadBy and b.TrackingDetails.BehindBy will be both null
               var commitsAhead = b.TrackingDetails.AheadBy;
               var commitsBehind = b.TrackingDetails.BehindBy;
               Console.WriteLine($"Branch {b.FriendlyName} is {commitsAhead} ahead and {commitsBehind} behind");
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the `HistoryDivergence` class. It adapts the `git_graph_ahead_behind` function from libgit2.

Comment: Constructor is declared internal, so how can it be used?

Comment: See the accepted answer. It is likely more correct.